# Substring in powershell

Tags: powershell

I usually use:

```
 $ext = [IO.Path]::GetExtension($file)
```

to get extensions from files. But there are cases where that will thrown an exception and I don't really care about that. So I am trying to do the same assuming input is just a string:

```
$a = $str.LastIndexOf('.')
$b = $str.length
$c = $b - $a
$ext = $str.Substring($str.LastIndexOf('.'), $c)
```

But is there a better/prettier way to do this, assuming input is string?

Comment: How about something like this: `Get-ChildItem $file -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Extension`

Comment: The point is that it need to work on something that is not necessarily a valid/existing file

Comment: Could you just split on periods then? `$ext = ($str -split '.')[-1]`

Comment: @BenH That's a wildcard.  I think you mean `'\.'` for literal period.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 That is indeed what I meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify this:

```
(Get-Item -Path $File).Extension
```

Alternatively:

```
PS C:\> $File = 'C:\Temp\Fold\File.exe'
PS C:\> $File -match '(?<Extension>\.\w+$)'
True
PS C:\> $Matches.Extension
.exe
```

or

```
PS C:\> ($File -split '\.')[-1]
exe
```

Comment: Check out OP's comment; it should work even if the path is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

One way is as per BenH's comment. Another is to use [Split-Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/split-path?view=powershell-5.1) to get only the filename first:

```
[string]$Path = "c:\path\to\somefile.withdots.csv"
$extension    = (Split-Path $path -Leaf).Split(".")[-1]
```